# javascript object property cannot be defined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have declared an object in JS and trying to assign a value to its properties.
But I can do it when only one property is defined, but not with more than one property.

**This works fine:**

```js
let User = {
  name
};

User['name']='Praveen';
alert(User.name);
```

**But this does not**

```js
let User = {
    name,
    email
};

User['name']='Praveen';
User['email']='incopraveen@gmail.com';

alert(User.email); //says email is not defined.
```

**NB: I have tried removing semicolons also.
        Tried dot notation also**

Comment: "*I have declared an object in JS*" - what did you think did the declaration do? Why didn't you just do `let User = {};`?

Comment: When running your code, I get an "*Uncaught ReferenceError: email is not defined*", not an alert. Because `name` and `email` *are* not defined anywhere. (Well, [`name` is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), that's probably why you weren't getting an exception in the first case).

Comment: `{ name }` is a short way of writing `{ name: name }`, so `name` has to be a symbol with a value for it to make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok, 
Please check do you have any existing `name,email` variable which you are set in the User Object,

I think you do not have existing name and email variable. So that It can not create the User Object itself.

You can do like this..

```
let User = {};
User['name']='Praveen';
User['email']='incopraveen@gmail.com';
```

This link could help you, https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/

Answer (score 5):

Because this:

```
 let User = {
   name,
   email
 };
```

is a shortform for:

```
 let User = {
   name: name,
   email: email,
 };
```

So it directly initializes both properties to the value that the *variables* `name` and `email` are holding. `name` is defined, it is the name of the page you are in, which you can easily check with:

```
  console.log(name);
```

but email is not defined yet, and trying to get an undeclared variable results in an error:

```
  console.log(email); // email is not defined
```

To solve that, explicitly declare both variables before:

```
  let name = "test";
  let email = "test@example.com";

  let User = {
   name,
   email
 };
```

Or initialize the properties not at all:

```
 let User = {};
```

or directly set the properties to a value:

```
  let User = {
   name: "test",
   email: "test@example.com",
  };
```